# Is there a time limit for the "Create your coterie" quest?

Tags: vtm-coteries-of-new-york

In the *Vampire the Masquerade: Coteries of New York" one of the first, very broad quests is to create your own coterie (a group of vampires working together). This in practice gives you a task to befriend 4 other vampires, each of them having their own tasks.

But each night, if you are lucky, you can at best do two visits. And on top of that, there are other activities that you are forced to pursue, so while I am on the 10th night, I haven't even spoken with two of the would-be "allies" and I have other side quest showing up (get rid of the reporter, investigate the cathedral etc).

So is there a time limit on this "create your coterie" quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough time to do everything on a single playthrough, and the maximum number of vampires I have managed to recruit is 3. The quest is, however, optional.

To say anything more than this would be providing story spoilers.

Comment: It seems that you are right, I've finished the game on the 17th night. Each of the "coterie quests" seem to require at least 4 nights to finish, so yes, there is a time limit.